# SSRS - Adding several tables in one report with different parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am developing a SSRS report for the first time from scratch.

I need to develop 3 reports (Ex: R1,R2,R3) in one main report. But the 3 reports have different parameters.

Is it possible to do so in one report such that, if R1 requires parameter P1 and R2 requires parameter P3 and P4 but when R2 is displayed P1 shouldn't be visible and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the visibility of each report based on the values of the parameters.

**Right-click Properties>Visibility>Show or Hide based on an expression**

And the expression would look something like this (I don't know what your parameters or values look like)

```
=iif(Parameters!parameter_name.Value = value, True, False)
```

**True = Hidden, False = Show report**